# Using squish(x) to fade in/out text

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use the [squish()](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) function to fade in/out text by using `alpha=squish(t-3)` to fade the text out and `alpha=1-squish(t-3)` to fade it in.

Fading out works well:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i color=#dddddd:s=640x480 -vf "drawtext='text=TEST:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=200:alpha=squish(t-3)'"
```

but fading in does not work at all:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i color=#dddddd:s=640x480 -vf "drawtext='text=TEST:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=200:alpha=1-squish(t-3)'"
```

Am I missing anything or is it a bug?

Comment: to see value, change to `...text='%{e\:1-squish(t-3)} TEXT'...` it is greater than 1

Comment: so change to `-1*squish(t-3)+1` :)

Comment: `-1*squish(t-3)+1` works correctly, and `text='%{e\:squish(t-3)} TEXT'`, shows that `squish(t-3)` goes (correctly) from 1 to zero, but `1-squish(t-3)` goes from 2 to 1, which is wrong; `1-1*squish(t-3)` is correct. Is it a bug or a feature?